# Bulk Insert in c# works after creating fresh db. Fails after. Always works in console

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

This is the SQL Command I am executing:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(4000);
SET @SQLString = N'BULK INSERT events FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@p0) +' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

The parameter @p0 is the path to the csv file and is added with `command.parameters.AddWithValue`

This works fine when I delete the db and let my program create it from scratch and then let it write into it.

However it fails when I close and reopen my application and use the now existing db.

The Error is:

> {"Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk
>   load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the
>   specified codepage) for row 2, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 3, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 4, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 5, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 6, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 7, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 8, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 9, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 10, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nBulk load data
>   conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
>   codepage) for row 11, column 4 (Timestamp).\r\nCannot bulk load
>   because the maximum number of errors (10) was exceeded.\r\nThe OLE DB
>   provider \"BULK\" for linked server \"(null)\" reported an error. The
>   provider did not give any information about the error.\r\nCannot fetch
>   a row from OLE DB provider \"BULK\" for linked server \"(null)\"."}

When I use the exact same sql command via query in the sql console, it works flawlessly.

What's strange is that (Timestamp) is not column 4. It's actually the very first column in the csv. How come the exact same query is working with the console but only sometimes (with new db) in C#?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: What does your connection string look like / how do you tell the code which database (catalog) to use (i.e. maybe you're connected to the right server/instance, but not looking at the right catalog).  (The reason you may see the error you're seeing is perhaps a previous attempt created a table with the same details under a different catalog / with a different collation).

Comment: When ever I see the wording "_Timestamp_" or similar date things, in a SQL data error message, I would guesstimate you have issues with your time/language format between data, application and/or database.

Comment: @JohnLBevan That was it! I somehow missed changing catalog when there already is an existing db.

Comment: @Thypari; great news; glad to help :)

Comment: @JohnLBevan Sorry I forgot that you can of course submit the answer yourself. So I can give you credit!

Comment: Thanks; your answer gives enough info if anyone else has the issue / I'm not too bothered about points.  Appreciate the thought though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohnBevan

In fact when I create the db I also changed the catalog. However when I used the already existing version, I did not call ChangeDatabase...

Comment: (Thanks @mjwills; I'm happy for @Thypari to take the points; just glad to help; appreciate the thought though)